# Are weighted metrics still metrics?

Tags: metric-spaces

I am trying to find any result regarding the properties of metrics that are weighted: are they still metrics? If the weights are fixed, it's clear they would still satisfy the properties of a metric. However, what about weights that are dependent on each pair of elements in the metric space?

For example:

$$d(u,u') = d'(u,u')\,w(u,u')$$

Comment: Obviously if the function $w$ is arbitrary it won't work.